# when form is submitted i want to show error message if checkbox is not selected?

Tags: angular, validation, checkboxlist

If no checkbox is selected I want to show error message. and hide error message when its checked. it is showing initially, when I deselect its not showing error message.Appreciate your help greatly. Thank you.

Here is my html code for three forms.

```
<div *ngIf="submitted && fc.cb.errors" class="error-feedback error">
                                                    <p *ngIf="fc.cb.errors.required" class="text-danger">
                                                        Please select atleast one policy
                                                    </p>
        
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let product of templateParamterTypes['cluster_network_policy']">
                                                <label class="form-check-label text-break">
                                            <input class="form-check-input form-control"
                                            type="checkbox" [value]="true" formControlName="cb" [(ngModel)]="product.isChecked"
                                            (change)="changeSelection(product.id)" /> {{ product.template_name }}
                                      <span class="form-check-sign">
                                        <span class="check"></span>
                                      </span>
                                        </label>

                                            </div>
```

ts:

```
 this.clusterForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      securityForm: this.formBuilder.group({
        clusternames: [null, Validators.required],
        label: [null, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)]],
       
        productFormGroup: this.productFG
      }),
   
    



changeSelection(id) {
    this.checkedIDs = []
    this.selectedItemsList = this.DisplayProductList.filter(product => product.isChecked);
    this.selectedTypes = this.selectedItemsList.reduce((a, i) => {
      if(a[i['policy_type']]){
        a[i['policy_type']] = [...a[i['policy_type']], i];
      }else{
        a[i['policy_type']] = [i];
      }
      return a;
    }, {});
    this.checkedIDs = this.selectedItemsList.map(item => ({ id: item.id }));

    const item = this.DisplayProductList.find(p => p.id === id);

    if (item.isChecked) {
      const fg: FormGroup = this.createFormGroup(item);
      this.productFArray.push(fg);
       return;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

take one variable like this ...

```
isCheckBoxSelected:boolean=false;
```

and make one method like this and put in (change) ...

```
checkboxChanged(){
    this.isCheckBoxSelected=!this.isCheckBoxSelected;
}
```

and in HTML instead of below code

```
[value]="true"
```

use this code

```
[value]="isCheckBoxSelected"
```

and change your if condition like this ...

```
*ngIf="submitted && !isCheckBoxSelected"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Sagar. I added your code and it showed error, after when i uncheck ,its not showing any error

Comment: You can check the current checkbox value inside OnClick function call , if it's not checked then you can display an error , it's algorithmic issue and a code issue

Comment: I tried but it somehow not working.I will share my onclick function code

Comment: I have added my click function method,

Comment: @Mercy can you share your codeon stackblitz and mention error appropriately.

Comment: sure @SAGARSOLANKI,I will share there and let you know

Comment: @SAGARSOLANKI I was trying to show error message for checkbox, when it is not selected on submit form. But its not working.

Comment: try this and if you get any error then share your code on stackblitz so I can see what is going on .
(change)="isCheckBoxSelected= $event.checked"